# How to do image processing with iPhoneSDK

Tags: ios4, image-processing, uiimageview, uiimage

How does one do image processing & manipulation in an iPhone application?

I would like to include below 3 important steps:

1. access raw RGB from image data
2. apply any image processing (edge detect, grey-scale, contrast & color).
3. create a new image from this modified data.

I got few links with color & contrast, but still looking for edge detection just from the corners of the image.

**Here are the links:**

https://launchpad.net/imagemagick/main/6.3.2-2

http://code.google.com/p/image-tools2009/source/checkout

http://www.google.com/codesearch#I0cABDTB4TA/pub/FreeBSD/

Is there any other **open source code** available for these functionalities?

Comment: CoreImage is the framework you are looking for

Comment: Nopes, I am looking for some open source API through which I can perform all edge detection & other image manipulation over image Or some help with code since I had never worked on the same.

Comment: It's MacOSX framework, How to use it with iPhoneSDK ?

Comment: even i m looking for the same, any kind of help is appreciated !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question highlights open source frameworks - but I'm going to throw my answer behind Apple's **CoreImage framework** that is now available in iOS5. CI has been around as an OSX framework for a very long time and as of iOS 5+ you can use a subset of the filters in iOS.

Advantages include:

- Very powerful
- Highly Optimised
- Been around for *ages*

Ray Wenderlich has great tutorials and he has one on ["Beginning Core Image in OS5"](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5689/beginning-core-image-in-ios-5) which I think might be right up your alley. He talks of the fundamental parts like `CIContext`, `CIImage`, `CIFilter`.

The second place you should look is the [Core Image Programming guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_tasks/ci_tasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001185-CH203-TPXREF101) and then [CoreImage Filter Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html) from Apple. The filter reference mentions which filters are available in iOS.

If you're finding that all a bit difficult, I think you may need to step backwards into CoreGraphics to learn the underlying basics of graphics on iOS -  but that's outside the scope of this question.

Comment: Thank for your answer,  but I have to work on the frameworks which are compatible with iOS 4 & 5 too . :(